# how to make the content inside div to display in one line

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have 4 labels inside a div, it looks like this:

[image]

I want them to display in one single line, how do I do this?

The code for labels:

```
      <div style="float:left; width:50%">

         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="loginPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="LoginLabel" runat="server"  CssClass="label-info" Font-Bold="true"  ForeColor="White"  Width="300px"/> 
            </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <%--Login ID--%>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="RolePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ShowRole" runat="server" CssClass="label-info" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" Width="300px"/>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <%-- role --%>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="timePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ShowTime" runat="server" CssClass="label-info" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" Width="300px"/>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <%--<br />--%>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="projPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
          <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ProjCount" runat="server"  CssClass="label-info" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" Width="300px"/> <%--project counter--%>
           </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with asp.net, but with a single css :

```
.label-info{
    display : inline-block;
    float : left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the part that has

> `<%--<br />--%>`

is breaking the line apart. Once changing that, the CSS bit `display: inline-block;` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following css property, because `<asp:label/>` gets rendered as `<div>`.

```
div.lable-info{
display:inline;
}
```